# batch file stops after cvs checkout

Tags: batch-file, cvs

I am just writing a small batch file that should checkout a module and build it using maven. But the batch file exits/stops after running the `cvs checkout` command. Below is the batch file contents.

```
call rmdir /S /Q C:\temp\project_folder
call cvs -q -d %CVSROOT% checkout -d C:\temp\project_folder module\workspace\project_folder
call cd C:\temp\project_folder
call mvn clean install
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Don't use `call` for normal internal commands (`rmdir`, `cd`) or programs (`cvs`, `mvn`) - `call` is for launching other batch files from the current one. Just use the commands/programs directly, and see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

The use of call is for generating a callback to the currently running batch file.  If you were to call another batch file without the call command it will transfer control to the new batch file and will not record where it came from.  With the call command it will remember what line of the batch file was executed and when the called batch file exits it will continue execution at the next line of the parent file.